# Overcoming ambiguity in HTMLAgility pack (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the InnerText of a particular node with the following xpath
    `/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/font/font/span`
by using the following
`doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/font/font/span").InnerText`

But instead it is returning me the InnerText with the following xpath 
`/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/font/font/span`

Am I making any mistake? Do I have to be more specific with the Xpath? If so, please help me by specifying how to be more specific.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML document (or a link to it)?

Comment: This is the link to the html document. http://tneb.tnebnet.org/tariff_new.html

Comment: When you use SelectNodes instead, it actually returns both nodes, this is due to a bug/feature in HAP. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a known behavior with regards to the handling of  tags to fix incorrectly written HTML. [There is a bug tracking this](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/23074) on the HTML Agility Pack website and luckily, there is a workaround for this.

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        // v== Add this line before loading a document
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form"); 
        doc.Load("doc.html");
```